# Issue with using Spring OAuth on Java8 standard environment

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

My sample application work on local environment. But, it does not work on Java8 standard environment. The following project is the sample application project.

https://github.com/nosix/appengine-java8-spring-oauth2

The following error occurs in Java8 standard environment:

```
Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token
```

I added logs to the source code of Spring OAuth and investigated the cause. The cause of the error seems to be that the session data has been lost.

It operated as follows:

`preservedState` is null in `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider::getParametersForTokenRequest`. So, `InvalidRequestException` is thrown. This is the cause of the error.

`setPreservedState` method is called in `OAuth2RestTemplate::acquireAccessToken`. At that time, `preservedState` is set to null.

`DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` instance has `preservedState`. `preservedState` of `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` instance is null in Java8 standard environment. But, It is not null in the local environment.

`DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` instance are stored in the session. I understand that it is stored on memory in the local environment and in the data store in the standard environment.

From the above, I guessed that the session data was lost.

I was stuck in the investigation. Is there information that serves as a clue for solving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Finally I implemented a custom `SessionRepository` of Spring Session as follows: ([see also this commit](https://github.com/int128/gradleupdate/commit/2405310dd0da4e19cf4d4b55a16f8466c1d62cc8))

Repository class:

```
class MemcacheSessionRepository(private val memcacheService: MemcacheService) : SessionRepository<MemcacheSession> {
  private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
  private val maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds: Int = 3600

  override fun createSession() = MemcacheSession().also { session ->
    session.maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds
    log.debug("createSession() = {}", session.id)
  }

  override fun save(session: MemcacheSession) {
    log.debug("save({}) with expiration {}", session.id, session.maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds)
    memcacheService.put(session.id, session, Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(session.maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds))
  }

  override fun getSession(id: String): MemcacheSession? =
    (memcacheService.get(id) as? MemcacheSession)?.also { session ->
        session.setLastAccessedTimeToNow()
    }.also { session ->
        log.debug("getSession({}) = {}", id, session?.id)
    }

  override fun delete(id: String) {
    log.debug("delete({})", id)
    memcacheService.delete(id)
  }
}
```

Entity class:

```
class MemcacheSession : ExpiringSession, Serializable {
  companion object {
    const val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
  }

  private val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
  private val creationTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
  private var lastAccessedTime: Long = creationTime
  private var maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds: Int = 3600
  private val attributes: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()

  override fun getId() = id

  override fun getCreationTime() = creationTime

  override fun getLastAccessedTime() = lastAccessedTime
  override fun setLastAccessedTime(time: Long) {
    lastAccessedTime = time
  }
  fun setLastAccessedTimeToNow() {
    lastAccessedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }

  override fun getMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds() = maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds
  override fun setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(interval: Int) {
    maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = interval
  }

  override fun removeAttribute(key: String) {
    attributes.remove(key)
  }

  override fun getAttributeNames() = attributes.keys

  override fun <T> getAttribute(key: String): T? = attributes[key] as T?

  override fun setAttribute(key: String, value: Any) {
    attributes.put(key, value)
  }

  override fun isExpired() = false
}
```

This seems work well at this time but it uses only Memcache and needs to improve for high availability.

Comment: Thanks man, this works! I converted stuff in your commit into Java, but other than that had no major issues.I cannot believe that storing sessions does not work in App Engine out of the box despite them saying it should :/

Comment: [The solution](https://github.com/int128/gradleupdate/commit/2405310dd0da4e19cf4d4b55a16f8466c1d62cc8) works. I made [DatastoreSessionRepository](https://github.com/nosix/appengine-java8-spring-oauth2/blob/master/application/src/main/kotlin/org/musyozoku/appengine/session/DatastoreSessionRepository.kt), referring to this. This also works. Thank you very much!

Comment: For non-Kotlin people, this might be helpful for copy-paste (feel free to replace lombok with explicit code) 
https://gist.github.com/lilianaziolek/6851c2f81be81eae2207ec863f41f484